# Как изменить и запушить измененые параметры git (head branch)

Tags: git

```
>> git remote show origin 
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@sphere.school.ru:vog
  Push  URL: git@sphere.school.ru:vog
  HEAD branch: ft_printf
  Remote branches:
    compare        tracked
    dev            tracked
    ft_printf      tracked
    it_works       tracked
    last           tracked
    master         tracked
    testing        tracked
    updd_ft_printf tracked
    with_struct    tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    compare merges with remote compare
    dev     merges with remote dev
    last    merges with remote last
    master  merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    compare        pushes to compare        (fast-forwardable)
    dev            pushes to dev            (fast-forwardable)
    it_works       pushes to it_works       (up to date)
    last           pushes to last           (up to date)
    master         pushes to master         (up to date)
    updd_ft_printf pushes to updd_ft_printf (up to date)
```

как изменить HEAD branch на другую ветку. Мне нужно, чтобы при `git clone` стояла другая ветка по умолчанию.

Comment: `git clone`  или `gut pull` или `git push`?

Comment: именно `git clone`

Comment: если «именно git clone», то локально вы повлиять не сможете. дейстовать надо только на той машине, где физически находится хранилище, из которого делаете клон. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3301956/4827341